# Svelte: Reactive declaration does not work when passing a declared function

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, sveltekit

### Problem

I created a *reactive* variable to sort an array when a *state* variable has changed. It does work if I declare the `sort` function directly as a callback, but not if I pass an already declared function.

### Code

So this is the code which does **not** work:

```
  const sortSongs = (a, b) => {
        const [option, direction] = sortOption.split("-");
        const itemA = a[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();
        const itemB = b[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();

        if (itemA < itemB) {
          return direction == "up" ? 1 : -1;
        }

        if (itemA > itemB) {
          return direction == "up" ? -1 : 1;
        }

    return 0;
  };

  $: filteredSongs =
    lessons
      ?.sort(sortSongs)
      .filter(lesson => lesson.title?.toLowerCase().includes(value)) || [];
```

And this the one who does work:

```
  $: filteredSongs =
    lessons
      ?.sort((a, b) => {
        const [option, direction] = sortOption.split("-");
        const itemA = a[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();
        const itemB = b[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();

        if (itemA < itemB) {
          return direction == "up" ? 1 : -1;
        }

        if (itemA > itemB) {
          return direction == "up" ? -1 : 1;
        }

        return 0;
      })
      .filter(lesson => lesson.title?.toLowerCase().includes(value)) || [];
```

### Confusion

So shouldn't both be working? Why does it make a difference where I declare the function? Here is a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/bf604af4617c414386e1de1a43793c78?version=3.47.0) to see this in action. The red songs got the not-working code, while the green ones have the working one.

Comment: What's to do in the Repl to see there's different behaviour?

Comment: Isn't this a simplified version of the problem you described?https://svelte.dev/repl/36e04a72cc54426095696f6d924cb085?version=3.47.0

Comment: @Corrl Just click on the sort checkboxes. The green items will move around while the red ones do not react. And yes, basically your REPL is a simplified version. But there is no button to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect `$: filteredSongs` to reevaluate when `sortOption` changes, but when you pass the function reference `.sort(sortSongs)`, `sortOption` is 'hidden' inside the function and not directly related to the reactive statement anymore. It's mentioned in the docs here in the [second paragraph](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-3-$-marks-a-statement-as-reactive)

> Only values which directly appear within the $: block will become dependencies of the reactive statement

A quick and dirty solution would be to pass `sortOption` as a parameter

```
?.sort(sortSongs, sortOption)
```

`.sort()` only expects the compare function as argument, so `sortOption` will be ignored, but is again a dependency because inside the `$:` block again

This would be a clearer alternative without calling `.sort()` with a 'redundant' argument

```
let lessons = [];
...

const sortSongs = (songs, sortOption) => {
        return songs.sort((a,b) => {
            const [option, direction] = sortOption.split("-");
            const itemA = a[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();
            const itemB = b[option == "Song" ? "title" : "artist"].toLowerCase();

            if (itemA < itemB) {
                return direction == "up" ? 1 : -1;
            }

            if (itemA > itemB) {
                return direction == "up" ? -1 : 1;
            }

            return 0;
        })     
    };

    $: filteredSongs =
        sortSongs(lessons, sortOption)
        .filter(lesson => lesson.title?.toLowerCase().includes(value));
```

Comment: Ok I understand it now. Thanks for the detailed explanation.